# Java: str.replaceAll() not working

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I'm trying to cleanse one String from another.

```
before = before.replaceAll(Constants.GENE_START_SEQUENCE, "");
```

And yet, the following assertion sometimes fails:

```
assert before.indexOf(Constants.GENE_START_SEQUENCE) == -1 : before;
```

This is what the assert spits out:

```
IIAOOOCOAAAOCCIOOOACAIAOACICOOIAIOOICIIOIIOICOICCCOOAOICOCOOIIOOAOAACIIOCCICIOIII
```

Comment: If you can provide a self-contained example, including the constants in question, that demonstrates the behavior described, I'll give you a cookie.

Comment: What is Constants.GENE_START_SEQUENCE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`replaceAll` only replaces occurences of the pattern in the original string. If the pattern reoccurs as a result of the replacement, this new occurence won't be replaced. Example:

```
"XXYY".replaceAll("XY", "");
```

This will find one occurence of "XY" (at index 1) and then replace that with "". The result will be "XY". If you want to prevent this from happening, you have to rexecute replaceAll, until `replaceAll` stops finding a match.

```
String string = "XXYY";
String oldString;
do {
  oldString = string;
  string = string.replaceAll("XY", "");
} while(!string.equals(oldString));
// string will now be ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that `Constants.GENE_START_SEQUENCE` is a valid regex pattern. If it isn't supposed to be a regular expression you should escape it using the quote method on java.util.regex.Pattern.